# laravel basic program not working with routing

Tags: laravel

am trying to develop a web application with the help of LARAVEL framework and am successfully installed the Laravel in my laptop.

I want to make a basic controller and a view program. and routing . is there any error in my program and reply to this question please.

My Controller,view, routes files are described in below

```
NewController.php

<?php

class New_Controller extends BaseController {



public function action_index()()
{
    return View::make('hai');
}

}


hai.php
```

Laravel Basics

```
<body>
<h1>Jishad is Developing Laravel 4</h1>
</body>
</html>

Routes.php

<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('hai');
});
```

Comment: where are all this located?

Comment: in E:\wamp\www\laravel\app

Comment: I mean the location of these specific files.

Comment: NewController.php is in Controller folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like following. Declare the route (It'll call `index` method from `NewController` when you access `home` page):

```
Route::get('/', 'NewController@index');
```

Now create your `NewController` like this:

```
// NewController.php
class NewController extends BaseController {

    // You may keep this line in your BaseController
    // so you don't need to use it in every controller
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    public function index()
    {
        // Make the view and pass a $name variable to the view with
        // Jishad as it's value and then set the $view to the layout
        $view = View::make('hai')->with('name', 'Jishad');
        $this->layout->content = $view;
    }
}
```

Now Since you are new to this framework so I would suggest to use controller layout instead of `blade` layout but you may find everything about `layout/templating` [here](http://laravel.com/docs/templates). To make it working you need to create the `master` layout in `app/views/layouts` folder like this:

```
// app/views/layouts/master.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Simple Web Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><?php echo $content; ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also need to create the `hai` view in `app/views` folder like:

```
// hai.php
<h1>Welcome TO Laravel</h1>
<p><?php echo $name ?> is developing learning Laravel</p>
```

You need to read more about `Laravel`, check the [Laravel - 4](http://laravel.com/docs?/docs/) documentation and read some `articles/books`. Also You used `action_index` but it was used in `Laravel - 3`, just use `index`.

Answer (score 0):

1.Your routing is wrong, if you want to point your route to a controller do this:

```
Route::get('/', 'NewController@action_index');
```

2.If the name of your controller is `NewController` then your class should also be that:

```
class NewController extends BaseController {

  public function action_index()
  {
    return View::make('hai');
  }

}
```

3.Also the `public function action_index()()` should be `public function action_index()`.

Comment: how can i run in my browser ?

Comment: @user3400396 well, that is another question and I think you should follow some simple tutorials instead. Rather than asking questions immediately.